# Translate Hard drive letter into the corresponding Device ID (or viceversa)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, wmi, wmic

I need to Identify the drive letter of a Manufacturer ID of a hard drive device (or maybe viceversa thing I could do it too).

The command to retrieve the manufacturer IDs:

```
WMIC.exe DiskDrive Get /Format:List
```

Example Output (splitted and with HTML entities formatted):

```
PNPDeviceID=DISK&VEN_WDC_WD10&PROD_02FAEX-00Z3A0
```

The command to retrieve the drive letters:

```
WMIC.exe Volume Get /Format:List
```

Example Output:

```
DriveLetter=C:
```

The problem is that I can't find any useful property that I could associate from both outputs to make a query, I mean I don't know what to do with the manufacturer IDs to search the drive letter of each ID, I can't see any way to identify the drive letter of the ID.

So at the moment that I get the DeviceID `DISK&VEN_WDC_WD10&PROD_02FAEX-00Z3A0` I need to translate it to the equivalent driveLetter, which is `C:`, that's all.

I've tried using `WMIC` tool 'cause I don't know how to associate this info using native commandline tools provided in Windows, but really is not full necessary for me to accomplis this task accesing to `WMI` Classes, I could accept a solution using other presintalled tools in Windows (maybe `BCDedit`?), or a solution in `VBScript` language should be accepted too, but for environment circunstances I can't do this task in any other languages (included native `PowerShell`) and also not using 3rd party tools like `Devcon` utility provided by Microsoft.

The reason why I need that is to finish this Script which should retrieve and exclude the DeviceID of the DriveLetter `C:`:

```
@Echo OFF & REM Mode con cols=150 lines=50

:: Exclude this drive during the process.
Set "ExcludedDrive=C:"

:: This variable should be set later,
:: Stores the device ID of the drive letter excluded above.
Set "ExcludedID="

REM ************
REM PSEUDO CODE:
REM ************
REM 
REM To get Volume Information:
REM WMIC.exe Volume Get /Format:List
REM WMIC.exe Volume Where 'DriveLetter="C:"' Get /Format:CSV
REM 
REM To get DiskDrive Information:
REM WMIC.exe DiskDrive Get /Format:List
REM 
REM :: Identify the drive letter of each DeviceID to add exclusions
REM For Each %%DriveLetter in %ExcludedDrive% do (
REM 
REM     :: Retrieve an WMIC Result
REM     Set WMIC_Query_Result=¿?
REM     Set WMIC_Query_Result_DriveLetter=¿?
REM     Set WMIC_Query_Result_DeviceID=¿?
REM 
REM     If %WMIC_Query_Result_DriveLetter% EQU %%DriveLetter (
REM         Set "ExcludedID=%WMIC_Query_Result_DeviceID%"
REM     )
REM )
REM 
REM ******************
REM END OF PSEUDO CODE
REM ******************

For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%a In (
    'REG.exe Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SCSI" ^| Find /I "Disk&"'
) Do (
    Echo "%%a" | Find /I "%ExcludedID%" || (
        For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%b In ('REG.exe Query "%%~a"') Do (
            Reg.exe ADD "%%b\Device Parameters\Disk" /V "UserWriteCacheSetting" /T "REG_DWORD" /D "0x00000000" /F 1>NUL
        )
    )
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is vague question for me, because one drive may contains many partitions.

Comment: @Xearinox I think not 'cause a partition is not a drive and a partition driveletter should point to the drive, I'm working with the Hard Drive Manufacturer ID of a drive.

Comment: Yes but you try convert letter to drive id if I understand. What if I have letters C,D,E on one disk.

Comment: @Xearinox yes but then all those partitions will points to the same hard drive as you know! :P then I imagine that should be able to retrieve the drive indiferentlly of the partition and the device ID of that drive (no matter if in that order), Anyways I will clarify that are one partition per disk (plus the hidden partition in C: that creates Windows OS) and has not a RAID, thanks for comment

Comment: @Xearinox - Not so fast :)  With disk striping and RAID technology, there can be a many to many relationship between physical drives and logical volumes. A single drive can contain many partitions (volumes), and a single volume can be spread across multiple drives. There ought to be a way to map between the two, but the many to many  relationship complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
diskpart /s diskpart.script
```

with two lines in the script

```
select disk 0
detail disk
```

help?

Comment: Yes, that was perfect to make a query in WMIC with the hard drive model, I've posted the solution if someone is interested to. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to get the Device ID of the Hard drive that stores the System (C:)

```
@Echo OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(
 REM Diskpart Script to get details about the System's Hard Drive.
 Echo Select Disk=System
 Echo Detail Disk
) > "%TEMP%\Diskpart.tmp"

For /F "Tokens=*" %%# in (
    'Diskpart /S "%TEMP%\Diskpart.tmp" ^| Find /I "Disk Device"'
) Do (
    For /F "Tokens=1,2,* Delims=\ " %%a in (
        'WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where Model^="%%#" Get PNPDeviceID /Format:CSV ^| Find /I "&amp;"'
    ) Do (
        Set "DeviceID=%%b"
        Set "DeviceID=!DeviceID:&amp;=&!"
    )
)

Echo "!DeviceID!"

Pause&Exit /B 0
```